# Discrete Math with recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUzFM.png)

Can you explain what the question ask?
I don’t need the direct answer, but would you mind tell me why 02231 is the sequence of 5 ?

Why the total number of sequence is 4 to the power of n?,

Answer (score 1):

The question says that $a_n$ is the number of strings of length $n$ containing the numbers 0,1,2,3 which also contain an odd number of $1$'s. So, for example, $a_1 = 1$, because "1" is the only sequence of length $1$ which contains an odd number of $1$'s. Any length 1 string except "1" would contain zero 1's, and zero is even. 02231 is an example if a string of length $5$ with an odd number of $1$'s because $1$ only appears once in this sequence, and one is an odd number. 11103 is also an example of a string of length $5$ with an odd number of $1$'s. 01122 is not an example, because it has two $1$'s, and two is even.

If you just want to count the number of $n$-length strings using 0,1,2,3, the total number is $4^n$, because you have four choices for each number in the string. The number of these strings containing an odd number of $1$'s is less than $4^n$, because you have to exclude all the strings that contain an even number of $1$'s.

The question wants you to find a relationship between the values $a_n$ and the values $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, ...$. If you've already computed $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n-1}$, how can you find $a_n$?

Comment: 01122 is a string of length 4 , is it correct ?

Comment: No, 01122 is a string of length 5. 00112 is not one of the strings you want to count, because the number if 1's is even.

Comment: I made a mistake above, that should say 01122 for both strings.

我看到你是香港人，好像你對這個問題的言語有一些不明白的地方。我的書面語不是很好，但是爲了加多點解釋，我盡可能用中文寫一下這個問題的意思。

你就要數有多少個滿足以下的特殊的含有n個字的數字符串:
- 1字的數量是奇數;
- 每一個數字是0，1，2，或 3.

01122有五個字，可是它含有兩個1字，所以這個數字符串是不用數的。

I hope that makes it a bit clearer =)

Comment: Thanks you very much.